# Not able to Upload Artifacts along with their folder structure to Jfrog using Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-groovy, jfrog-cli

I am using Pipeline Job which should upload all the jars to the Jfrog, it's working but it is uploading all the jars without its folder structure to Jfrog.

eg:

```
libs-release-local/one.jar

libs-release-local/two.jar
```

But I want to upload all the jars along with their folder structure like below.

eg:

```
libs-release-local/abc/efg/abc/one.jar

libs-release-local/ABC/EFG/ABC/two.jar
```

**Note: here the folder structure may change based on the jar.**

So how do I make changes in a script which will catch the folder structure and upload it for every jar?

Here is the current script am using

```
        stage('Uploading to artifactory'){
            steps{
                rtUpload (
                 serverId:"<server id>" ,
                  spec: '''{
                   "files": [
                      {
                      "pattern": "**/*.jar",
                      "target": "libs-bt-test-local/"
                      }
                            ]
                           }''',
                        )
            }
        }
```

Let me know if there a possible way to include a loop which will dynamically change the directory structure for every jar.

Answer (score 0):

The target value can be edited with a placeholders in order to dynamically determine the uploaded path.

For example: libs-bt-test-local/{1}

For further information and examples, you may refer to the Artifactory REST API documentation page:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders